# Why is the lift coefficient not 0 at the initial time t* = 0?

Tags: aerodynamics

In an experiment on pitching airfoil. Experimental results are given by the following graph, the curves are the evolutions of the lift coefficient.
Why is the lift coefficient not zero at the initial time t* = 0?
[image]
At t* = 0 then the angle of attack is 0 degrees. As we know at AoA = 0, CL must be 0 right?

[Link to the paper Unsteady lift on a high-amplitude pitching aerofoil](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00348-020-03095-2)

Comment: I suppose it depends on the definition of AoA - if zero is the point at which Cl is zero then it does seem to be paradoxical, but if it’s based on a line between the most widely-spaced extremes of the wing section then some lift might be expected at this angle.

Comment: Let me know if [this answer of mine](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/98958/64684) is of any help. Basically when the airfoil oscillate above a certain speed then $C_l$ is not only proportional to $\alpha$ but also to the speed and the acceleration by which $\alpha$ changes

Comment: What is "k" please?

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni: k is the *reduced frequency*. You find the definition in my answer I linked here above.

Comment: @sophit thanks.  Not ASE related, but I wonder if marine life benefits from any of this as they oscillate (swim).  Fish seem incredibly good at holding their place in a current with minimal motion.

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni: fishes remain aloft using buoyancy, they are more like Zeppelins than airplane, the less they move the better they hold their place.

Comment: @sophit  not buoyancy, propulsion.  Holding place *in a current*.  The reverse stroke can recover some energy of (water moved by the) 1st stroke.

Comment: "*As we know at AoA = 0, CL must be 0 right?*". Only for symmetrical airfoils. The angle where CL is null is the *angle of zero lift*. See [How do you calculate the lift coefficient of an airfoil at zero angle of attack?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/54736/3201)